# special characters in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql DB contains arabic data. when opening the db via mysql workbench the data looks like "ßÇÙã ÇáÌãÇÓí".

when making a simple php file that read from the DB the data looks fine(arabic).

but when reading the data via ASP.net the data looks like "ßÇÙã ÇáÌãÇÓí".

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Before running SELECT query from your ASP.net application try running two queries after you connect to the database:

```
SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'; 
SET NAMES utf8;
```

Basically you need to make your app aware of possible international characters.

P.S. This should be run again every time connection is established, e.g. you can't run it once from MySQL workbench and fix your app. Your app need to do that on its own.